# How to get system time in Java without creating a new Date

Tags: java, date, memory-management

I need to get the system date, and Java provides the `new Date().getTime()`.

But I need to avoid new object allocation (I'm working on a embedded system). How can I get the system time without allocating a new `Date` object?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As jzd says, you can use `System.currentTimeMillis`. If you need it *in* a `Date` object but don't want to create a *new* `Date` object, you can use `Date.setTime` to reuse an existing `Date` object. Personally I hate the fact that `Date` is mutable, but *maybe* it's useful to you in this particular case. Similarly, `Calendar` has a `setTimeInMillis` method.

If possible though, it would probably be better just to keep it as a `long`. If you only need a timestamp, effectively, then that would be the best approach.

Answer (score 53):

This should work:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

At least in OpenJDK, [`Date`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) uses this under the covers.

The call in [`System`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.currentTimeMillis%28%29) is to a native JVM method, so we can't say for sure there's no allocation happening under the covers, though it seems unlikely here.

Answer (score 8):

Use **System.currentTimeMillis()** or **System.nanoTime()**.

Comment: From the documentation on nanoTime(): This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change. Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow.

Comment: I believe @AaronF meant 2^63 nanoseconds. :-)

Comment: @pianoJames Yeah. That's embarrassing. Gave me a laugh. Thanks for the comment.