# Get system time and convert to string

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to get the `System` date and time and use that in the `setFile()` method to prevent overwriting my output files. Any idea how I can do that? I went down the path of `Calendar.YEAR`, etc. but that will give me model date and time not System. Any suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get system time in Java without creating a new Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863658/how-to-get-system-time-in-java-without-creating-a-new-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create a String of your current system time using:

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
String dateAsString = currentDate.toString();
```

Use that in your `setFile()` method for the filename and you will never overwrite any outputs (unless you ran them in the same exact second :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I was also able to implement using a `SimpleDateFormat` as follows

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); 
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss");
String strDate = "myFile"+ dateFormat.format(date)+".txt"; myFile.setFile(strDate, myFile.WRITE);
```